# Azure batch windows container workloads remove quotes from provided command line

Tags: windows, docker, azure-batch

When using windows container workloads on Azure Batch quotes are stripped from command line arguments if they do not contain a space.

We are using the newest C# SDK 13.0.0 and node VMs SKU windows server 2019 with containers.

Repro:
Create job and a task running inside a docker container (e.g. based on the docker image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019)
use command line of `cmd /S /C mkdir "c:/foo"` - see that inside the docker container the command is executed as `cmd /S /C mkdir c:/foo` - which will fail.

The same issue is described in this open containers PR: https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/commit/deb4d954eafc4fc65f04c00a08e08c3e69df32d0

Edit: I realized that this was more as statement than a question... so here is the question:
What is a workaround/fix for this behavior?

**Edit powershell -EncodedCommand Solution**:
I accepted the environment variable solution but we are using a different one.
We use "`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand`" - doing so hides quotes and backslashes from CommandLineToArgsvW and docker - meaning the commandline gets put together properly inside the docker container on the azure batch vm. (In C# this is done by  `var base64EncodedCmd = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cmd));`) Take care to escape powershell properly as well. e.g. the encoded command could be something lik `"& my.exe --% --input \\\"userprovidedparam\\""` (using powershells "stop parsing" --%) otherwise e.g. a value of $(Get-Date) would be evaluated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this is an issue with the runtime, a potential workaround is to create a `.cmd` or `.bat` file that contains the commands you would like to run. You can associate this file as a [ResourceFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/resource-files) or bake it into a custom container.

Comment: For the simple example this is a a valid solution. For commands with user provided arguments we run into issues though - how would we hand them over? In environment variables?

Comment: Environment variables would be my suggested approach.

Comment: thanks people - environment variables are an adequate solution to the problem (with some additional escaping). we will go down a different route using powershell -EncodedCommand (i'll answer add our solution to my question)